# Does Java treat multiple slashes "\\\\\\" as single "\\" in file path?

Tags: java, string

The line and the commented line below produces the same results:

```
public class StringEscapeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String fileName = "C:\\Dev\\TryEclipseJava\\StringEscape\\\\\\f.txt";
        /* String fileName = "C:\\Dev\\TryEclipseJava\\StringEscape\\f.txt";*/

        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File exists!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("File does not exist!");
        }
    }
}
```

Does Java always treat any slash sequence of more than 2 slashes the same as "\"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `\` is used to escape, which means

- `C:\\Dev\\TryEclipseJava\\StringEscape\\\\\\f.txt`

  will be compiled to

  `C:\Dev\TryEclipseJava\StringEscape\\\f.txt`.

and

- `C:\\Dev\\TryEclipseJava\\StringEscape\\f.txt`

  will be compiled to

  `C:\Dev\TryEclipseJava\StringEscape\f.txt`.

---

When you create a `File` instance with:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
```

The `fileName` will be "normalized" according to your `FileSystem`:

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

In the "normalize" procedure of `WinNTFileSystem`,

`C:\Dev\TryEclipseJava\StringEscape\\\f.txt`

will be truncated to:

`C:\Dev\TryEclipseJava\StringEscape`

Then it will:

> Remove redundant slashes from the remainder of the path, forcing all
>   slashes into the preferred slash

Finally, `fileName` is normalized as:

`C:\Dev\TryEclipseJava\StringEscape\f.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java does not treat these Strings as the same. A literal `\` has to be *escaped* by prefixing it with another `\`.

So `\\` is one backslash, and `\\\\\\` is three.

Only once you use the String as a path to a `File` on a platform where `\` is the delimiter (Windows …) are the extra backslashes stripped. See the more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397998/9131078) by user6690200.

Comment: It is not Windows that eliminates the extra backslashes, it is the Java `File` class, and it certainly deals with ``\`` in special ways.